# ERROR: gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 45] Operation not supported

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud, apple-m1

I'm attempting to `gcloud app deploy` on a new machine, and I get this `[Errno 45] Operation not supported` crash partway through the process. Verbose output from my terminal below.

I'm replicating an existing install from an Intel MBP to a new M1 MacBook Pro. I encountered some Python issues during this that appeared to be processor-dependent, so I'm wondering whether that might be relevant here.

Hoping for a fix to get this deployment process running.

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.app.deploy] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
DEBUG: Loading runtimes experiment config from [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml]
INFO: Reading [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x110aa6970>]
DEBUG:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/storage/storage_api.py", line 313, in ReadObject
    self.client.objects.Get(get_req, download=download)
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/storage/v1/storage_v1_client.py", line 1079, in Get
    return self._RunMethod(
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 715, in _RunMethod
    download.InitializeDownload(http_request, client=self.client)
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 327, in InitializeDownload
    raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(response)
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpNotFoundError: HttpError accessing <https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/runtime-builders/o/experiments.yaml?alt=media>: response: <{'x-guploader-uploadid': 'ADPycdvcTNGdBwKN2VQu31VfVvUOVK-swfpykYVDPgoXsaW9jze0rCWlasT9nA3BvJOIi-MQD_xNqhLtShiUBj1LEXwCnsr8cQ', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Sat, 18 Sep 2021 23:55:07 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'expires': 'Sat, 18 Sep 2021 23:55:07 GMT', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'content-length': '49', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'status': '404'}>, content <No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/runtime_builders.py", line 269, in _Read
    with contextlib.closing(storage_client.ReadObject(object_)) as f:
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/storage/storage_api.py", line 315, in ReadObject
    raise exceptions.BadFileException(
googlecloudsdk.calliope.exceptions.BadFileException: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x110aa6970>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
DEBUG: Experiment config file could not be read. This error is informational, and does not cause a deployment to fail. Reason: Unable to read the runtimes experiment config: [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml], error: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x110aa6970>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/storage/storage_api.py", line 313, in ReadObject
    self.client.objects.Get(get_req, download=download)
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/storage/v1/storage_v1_client.py", line 1079, in Get
    return self._RunMethod(
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 715, in _RunMethod
    download.InitializeDownload(http_request, client=self.client)
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 327, in InitializeDownload
    raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(response)
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpNotFoundError: HttpError accessing <https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/runtime-builders/o/experiments.yaml?alt=media>: response: <{'x-guploader-uploadid': 'ADPycdvcTNGdBwKN2VQu31VfVvUOVK-swfpykYVDPgoXsaW9jze0rCWlasT9nA3BvJOIi-MQD_xNqhLtShiUBj1LEXwCnsr8cQ', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Sat, 18 Sep 2021 23:55:07 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'expires': 'Sat, 18 Sep 2021 23:55:07 GMT', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'content-length': '49', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'status': '404'}>, content <No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/runtime_builders.py", line 269, in _Read
    with contextlib.closing(storage_client.ReadObject(object_)) as f:
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/storage/storage_api.py", line 315, in ReadObject
    raise exceptions.BadFileException(
googlecloudsdk.calliope.exceptions.BadFileException: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x110aa6970>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/runtime_builders.py", line 518, in LoadFromURI
    with _Read(uri) as f:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/runtime_builders.py", line 276, in _Read
    raise FileReadError(six.text_type(e))
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.runtime_builders.FileReadError: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x110aa6970>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 145, in _ServerSideExperimentEnabled
    experiment_config = runtime_builders.Experiments.LoadFromURI(
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/runtime_builders.py", line 522, in LoadFromURI
    raise ExperimentsError(
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.runtime_builders.ExperimentsError: Unable to read the runtimes experiment config: [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml], error: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x110aa6970>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
DEBUG: API endpoint: [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1]
DEBUG: Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Services to deploy:

descriptor:                  [/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/make/app/app-gamma/app.yaml]
source:                      [/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/make/app/app-gamma]
target project:              [app-gamma]
target service:              [default]
target version:              [20210918t165507]
target url:                  [https://app-gamma.wm.r.appspot.com]
target service account:      [App Engine default service account]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

DEBUG: No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
DEBUG: Using bucket [gs://staging.app-gamma.appspot.com].
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
INFO: Using ignore file at [/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/make/app/app-gamma/.gcloudignore].
DEBUG: Skipping file [.gcloudignore]
DEBUG: Skipping file [.gitignore]
DEBUG: Skipping file [.git]
DEBUG: Skipping file [__pycache__]
DEBUG: [Errno 45] Operation not supported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/files.py", line 628, in AddFileContents
    chunk = fp.read(4096)
OSError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 984, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 123, in Run
    return deploy_util.RunDeploy(
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 680, in RunDeploy
    deployer.Deploy(
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 448, in Deploy
    manifest = self._PossiblyUploadFiles(image, service_info,
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 371, in _PossiblyUploadFiles
    manifest = deploy_app_command_util.CopyFilesToCodeBucket(
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/deploy_app_command_util.py", line 304, in CopyFilesToCodeBucket
    manifest = _BuildDeploymentManifest(
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/deploy_app_command_util.py", line 90, in _BuildDeploymentManifest
    sha1_hash = file_utils.Checksum.HashSingleFile(full_path,
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/files.py", line 716, in HashSingleFile
    return Checksum.FromSingleFile(input_path, algorithm=algorithm).HexDigest()
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/files.py", line 703, in FromSingleFile
    return Checksum(algorithm=algorithm).AddFileContents(input_path)
  File "/Users/jdoe/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/files.py", line 631, in AddFileContents
    self.__hash.update(chunk)
OSError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported
ERROR: gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 45] Operation not supported
```

Comment: The crash is caused by **runtime-builders/experiments.yaml** missing.

Comment: @JohnHanley that error is irrelevant, I'm getting that every time even when the deploy is successful.

Comment: This looks like you dont have Cloud Build enabled in your project, can you check it here: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds ? Eventually does your service account have enough permissions to write into Cloud Storage to save build artifacts there?

Comment: I'm fairly certain cloud build is enabled for the project. I'm able to perform this exact operation on another (Intel) MBP. Perhaps there's some other configuration step for the local machine that I forgot to enable when setting it up.

My ultimate workaround was to mirror my GitHub repo to Google Source and have Cloud Build run and deploy directly to GAE whenever I tag a new release—
https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories